# Python Changing a the value of a string variable

Tags: string, python-2.7, variables, setvalue

I'm new to python, and I just want to know a way of changing a set string variable.

For example:

```
name ='school'
```

How would I go about changing this if I wanted to use the name variable for a different value like `George`, `Ben`, `Jess`, `Katie`, etc.

Comment: like any other language really.. just assign the name variable to a new String value.

Answer (score 2):

You can assign a new value to a variable in the same way you originally assigned a value to it: Using the assignment operator, `=`.

```
name = 'school'
print 'the current value of name is:', name
name = 'George'
print 'the current value of name is:', name
```

Result:

```
the current value of name is: school
the current value of name is: George
```